# Can a motherboard work when only supplied with ATX12V?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, atx

I am thinking of making a silent NAS for 3-4 people. Today I bought:

1. 4TB Western Digital HDD
2. 2x4GB DDR3 204 pin RAM
3. [Supermicro X10SBA](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/celeron/X10/X10SBA.cfm) motherboard which has 24 pin and 4 pin power connector.

Does 24 pin ATX is a must? Can I run this motherboard with only 4 pin 12V connector?

Comment: I don't think 4 pin will be enough, you will need to provide power to all power inputs, not only one out of two. the 24 pin provides the main power while 4 pin provides power to other sub components

Comment: Edited to remove the purchasing recommendation (which would have caused this to be closed).

Comment: a point regarding the part that was edited out. The PicoPSU power supplies are often sold without the ACDC brick Adaptors. So those two links you mentioned, look like one of the PicoPSU and one with the brick adaptor, so to get that power supply running you need both.

Comment: Furthermore, if it was the case that you needed a full blown PSU, then you can get fanless ones of those too. like fanless 300W+ PSUs. Also, even a basic motherboard can run NAS software.. I recall from a chat with allquixotic, he said a NAS is almost always a computer+samba solution. I suppose perhaps even a raspberry pi could run it. And allquixotic mentioned the netgear N900 and that many others support it. that router is fanless

Comment: @barlop That is true; I run a real NAS that I built (A full-fledged Debian server, with Apache, exim, antivirus, Samba, BIND9, et al.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your board is a Mini-ITX board. The Mini-ITX standard does not specifiy a standard for power supply, to find out what power supply you will need you must go read the manual.

From the manual page 2-19 I found (emphasis mine):

> ATX PWR & 12V DC PWR Connectors (JPW1 & PJ1)
>
> The 24-pin ATX power connector (JPW1) is used to provide power to the motherboard. **The
>   4-pin 12V DC PWR connector (PJ1) can also be used as an optional power
>   source when ATX power supply is not avail- able.** These power
>   connectors meet the SSI EPS 12V specification.

So no, you don't need a ATX supply, a 4 pin 12V supply will work fine as long as it supplies enough power (144 watts).

Comment: If I only get 4 pin 12V DC PWR adapter how will I get the power for SATA? I had checked the manual but I couldn't see it.

Comment: @borayeris  that manual is for the MBRD. the PicoPSU has a sata connector coming off it that can go to a device.  http://resources.mini-box.com/online/PWR-PICOPSU-160-XT/moreimages/picoPSU-160-XT-big2.jpg as well as the 12V 4pin  and a 24pin ATX connector  The PicoPSU is only Pico in dimensions.. and the mini itx is only mini itx in dimensions.. the mini itx board's power connectors are same as atx. And the PicoPSU's power connector's are ATX

Comment: Scott,  the 4 pin 12V connector is just as much an ATX connector as the 24pin "main power connector".  http://www.formfactors.org/developer%5Cspecs%5Catx2_2.pdf    "ATX12V power connector"(the 2x2 connector)

Comment: @barlop Yes it may match ATX's 12V connector for this specific board for convenience but the [Mini-ITX specification](http://www.formfactors.org/developer%5Cspecs%5CMini_ITX_Spec_V2_0.pdf) does not specify a connector shape or voltage it only has "recommendations" that the manufacturer uses SFX, TFX, FlexATX, or a external adapter. (And I said you don't need a ATX power supply, not that you don't need a ATX 2x2 connector)

Comment: I suppose they'd give the same voltages and the connectors would have the same shapes. A look on google at these things, some have 20pin or 24pin  main connector(that's an ATX thing), some(maybe all or most) have the P4/2x2 connector, (that's an ATX thing to have it or even not to have it!), and they have the SATA power connector or 4 pin molex.. It all looks pretty much the same really, just difference in SIZE.. So a PicoPSU of 300W (if there were one) would work in an ATX board. I see a 300W SFX PSU..

Comment: And there's this line on this webpage. http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/power-supply-specifications-atx-reference,3061-4.html ".Whether you will use an ATX-or SFX-based power supply in a given system depends more on the case or chassis than the motherboard."Each has the same basic electrical connectors the main difference is which type of power supply the case is physically designed to accept."[and note, sfx comes in different shapes..any issues regearding the right connectors are along the lines of 20pin or 24pin,and the P4 12V 2x2.So,same issue with an ATX board,diff ATX specs.

Comment: so main or the difference is physical dimensions, watts, number of SATA/MOLEX power connectors for peripherals. but as to whether it would fit, the same issue goes for any spec but any would fit..  but nice one for finding that with that MBRD he can get by even without the main power connector, not that he'd need to, but, good to know!

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard is powered by the 20- or 24-pin connectors, usually around the back of the board. This powers all the little chips, the CPU, the memory, the controllers, etc. The 4-pin auxiliary power connector is for modern CPUs, where they need dedicated power, and for the PCIe or AGP slots. You can use a regular ATX Power Supply

This motherboard/CPU combo, though, is also able to be powered by the 12V connector. I would recommend buying whichever will work best for you, depending on the space inside the case. If you get a regular ATX power supply, though, you can then power your hard drives and other peripherals, and it's easy to get replacements locally.

Comment: For your first paragraph, that would be true if this was a ATX motherboard, but it is not, it is a Mini-ITX. I would take it out as it kind of makes your answer confusing.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I don't mention that it's an ATX motherboard, I mention it uses an ATX power connector (the 20- or 24-port power connector)

Comment: Yes, but the way you phrase your answer the first time I read it I thought you where saying you *must* use the ATX power connector. I am just saying it could use some re-phrasing.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ahh, I understand where you may have been confused. I'll edit it

Comment: I understand like Scott too. Now are you both clear about just 4 pin can be used?

Comment: No. You need to get either one of the adapters, but the smaller one has a set of breakout cables to plug in to the bigger plugs.

Comment: re your last sentence(about regular ATX power supply). Even with a very low power PicoPSU (I think I one had a 60W one!) you can also power peripherals via the kind of power supplies that USB-IDE adaptors use.A plug can go into hte mains and have a wire with a SATA power connector or a 4 pin molex connector.I did it years ago when I used a fanless PicoPSU type thing,that couldnt power many peripherals so I powered the peripherals externally like that.But there are big fanless ATX PSUs nowadays too.Also Regular sized MBRDs these days are fanless too.+Picos now might be enough watts.

Comment: It would be against my recommendation, but yes, you can do that. I still prefer the full sized power supplies, as I know it has everything I need, and the right cables without putting in extra adapters

Comment: you may think it's neater but no harm in it so it's personal preference, and I think if you can do both then that's preferable, fun, flexible. though sure you could say you may as well just use one big power supply. he'd want fanless. could do. may be pricey.

Comment: @CanadianLuke perhaps you could include pics to explain "the smaller one has a set of breakout cables to plug in to the bigger plugs" and to answer borayeris's question about "I understand like Scott too. Now are you both clear about just 4 pin can be used? " your answer to him was "No..." perhaps you can illustrate?

Comment: @borayeris The adapter your originally pointed to will work, and have the breakout cables you need; they still need to be plugged in to the 24- or 20-port power plug, and the 4-pin by the CPU. The manual will show where everything gets plugged in